# Restful Web Services to HTML table

Tags: javascript, xml, rest, netbeans, restful-url

I have created a Restful web services from netbeans 8.2 for mysql table users and it gives the following xml output in localhost,

my localhost url : http://localhost:8080/siteuser/webresources/site.users/

This is the output:

```html
<userss>
<users>
<email>abcd@gmail.com</email>
<id>1</id>
<password>81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055</password>
<userType>user</userType>
<username>new</username>
</users>
<users>
<email>abcd@gmail.com</email>
<id>2</id>
<password>81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055</password>
<userType>admin</userType>
<username>kamal</username>
</users>
</userss>
```

I want to show this details in a html table so I wrote a code for it.But it doesn't work.
Can you help me to solve this problem? Thank You!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get API data from DB</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var url  = "http://localhost:8080/siteuser/webresources/site.users/";
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th></th>Email<th>ID</th><th>Password</th><th>User Type</th><th>User Name</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("users");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("email")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("password")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("userType")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("username")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button nothing happens in the browser but, following errors are showing in the browser console.

- Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/siteuser/webresources/site.users/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
- Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
- GET http://localhost:8080/siteuser/webresources/site.users/ net::ERR_FAILED
  loadXMLDoc @ index.html:27
  onclick @ index.html:13

@ index.html:27 = xmlhttp.send();

```html
   @ index.html:13 =  <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get API data from DB</button>
```

Comment: what doesn't work ? did you got any error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,When I click the button,nothing happens

Comment: does your browser console shows any error ? if yes ,post that as well

Comment: I looked the browser console now thanks to you. I will post the errors now

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) post .

Comment: Thanks.It solves my problem. I have to install a extension named Access-control-allow-origin to Chrome and It worked.